# Is it possible/reasonable to sneak solo/duo Baron?

Tags: league-of-legends

Basically is it possible/reasonable to sneak Baron or is it **too hard or too long?** I have tried to search for an answer and most answers are about the old Baron. Emphasis on the **sneak** part, I would think of doing this **extra early** when nobody is thinking about Baron, fully knowing that if you get caught even by one roaming enemy you're gonna die.

I am curious, and know that probably a Baron at such an early stage isn't even worth it, but still; Free **global exp and gold**. I wonder if in a low ELO atmosphere such as mine it's possible to take advantage of it (warding and counter-warding cautiously of course).

Comment: I deleted my awnser because I'm a moron and thought you meant Dragon not baron, sorry

Comment: thanks anyway! =) please upvote so I have enough rep to start commenting and upvoting and such xD

Answer (score 6):

In 99% of the cases, doing Baron while the enemy team is still up is a bad Idea for soloqueue. Especially during earlier stages of the game, Nashor just deals way too much damage and 2 enemy teammembers can potentially kill 5 People who are busy fighting for the buff.

So in general you should absolutely refrain from doing baron early, especially if you want to "sneak" it with a few players.

Now there is still this 1% where it's actually not too bad of an Idea. 
First of all, if you do this, you should make sure that you are somewhat ahead. Also you want to bring as much sustained damage as possible in order to get the buff. For early duo barons you'll either need Marksmen who build or gain attack speed (Jinx/Vayne) or champions that can force Baron to switch targets (Shaco/Heimerdinger). Also it's extremely helpful to have a tank that deals % target health damage (Amumu/Nasus). Warwick is also very helpful

**Conclusion**
It is Possible and ok to do in very few situation, however most of the time you can do something else that is a lot safer and just as rewarding so in general: don't do it.

If you see something like this in an LCS game remember that these players are the absolute elite and that they are playing extremely situational.

Comment: To add on this:I've seen a video on youtube where a heimerdinger solos baron pretty fast around the 20 minute mark(I can't search for it on my handy). If you are REALLY fed early it's possible. However you'll always have the risk that you're not only get killed by roaming enemies but also that they potentially can complete baron.

Comment: Yes, everything you say is true, generally the risks are much greater than the benefits, and what I wondered was more of a "3 players keep the other team busy while a couple at most do baron", and it doesn't really seem worthwhile...
And yeah, I know that most LCS things should be labeled with "Do not try this at home" for us more casual players haha :D

Comment: I think the most important thing when planning to sneak baron is to ward the approaches, and if the enemy team comes run away.

Comment: Good answer, but it's probably worth adding that you should ALWAYS bring 1-2 pinks along to make sure they don't have the pit warded before you begin.

Comment: @gruntswilldie I saw the video, but in the video, the heimer was a bit fed. And a heimer that is not on the line is something really fishy, that will most likely trigger some scouting to know what he is doing (as a normal heimer would push 24/7 his line).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so your specific question has for the most part been answered.  (It's doable but generally inadvisable).

I'd just like to add that rather than soloing/duoing baron, having your whole team sneak baron can be extremely effective in lower elos – specifically when your team is losing and the opposing team has control of dragon.  Generally if you have the timer on dragon but the enemy team has control/will flat out win in a fight, you can rush baron down once the enemy team heads toward their "free" dragon.  In Bronze/Silver I've found that teams focusing on early dragon control almost never even have baron warded.

Mind you, messing this up can be catastrophic.  This is more of a hail mary play than a good general strategy.  But I've turned many "sure losses" into victories by convincing teammates who have all but given up to just try this one last play.

Comment: I don't think this would even fit in a comment.

Comment: I would've made it shorter.  Also apparently I can comment on my own posts.

Comment: Yes. You can always comment on your own post. Sometimes adding on top of an existing answer can be viable. The judgements depends on how elaborate the new answer is and how well it stands on its own. This, I personaly think, is fine as its own answer.

Comment: This is perfectly fine as a standalone suggestion! Yes, I've tried and managed to call for a sneak baron with the whole team while they were cleaning up our jungle and that "free dragon", and failed just as many times, but it's a good option as long as you know to retreat if you see the enemy coming.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say it depends on which champions you are using for example full build master yi can solo baron pair him with a very tanky champ like thresh or bard (picked these two because of their kits) and you can potentially sneak it. 
When you can do it is situational. How far ahead if you team how far ahead is the enemy team where is the enemy team have they warded do they refresh the ward do they have teleport or some global ultimate etc. Their a lot of variables to consider but its not impossible to do, it takes far too much time and usually will throw the game if they wise up.
Regardless its very situational

Comment: Yes, it really doesn't sound doable, since it can throw the game and 2 missing players so late in the game is suspicious... thanks =)

Comment: I've seen warwick solo the baron, he wasn't full build but he was moderately fed. We did a push with 4 bot lane and he went and solo'd baron while we did it.

Comment: I completely forgot about warwick but main issue is getting in undetected warwick has zero mobility aside from bloodscent in that situation though yes sneaking baron would be easy if your team had warded someone could have tp when he was low and killed him and maybe taken baron as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it mid to late game. Earliest at 20 min.

Typically to solo him you basically need near full build. However there are numerous cheese tactics with different champions that work. Ex: Heimerdinger ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r420qfrW3fw))

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Clearly some champions are better suited for this then others. It is way easier to duo Baron and can be done with about any tank/sustain + dps combo.